# Match 2 Pulse Secure events with 1 regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to match 2 events with 1 regular expression and need some help.

**REGEX**

```
^(?:[^\.\n]*\.){6}\d+\s+\w+\s+(?P<software>\w+\-\w+/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s+\(\w+\s+\d+\)\s+\w+/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

**Match**

```
Mar 31 02:37:38 vpn PulseSecure: 2020-03-31 02:37:38 - vpn - [192.168.17.249] FRED(DUO-Windows)[] - Agent login succeeded for FRED/DUO-Windows from 192.168.17.24 with Pulse-Secure/8.3.4.1333 (Windows 10) Pulse/5.3.4.1333.
```

*software* Pulse-Secure/8.3.4.1333 (Windows 10) Pulse/5.3.4.1333

**No match**

```
Mar 31 03:01:13 vpn PulseSecure: 2020-03-31 03:01:13 - vpn - [192.168.17.24] FRED(DUO-Mac)[Mac] - Agent login succeeded for FRED/DUO-Mac from 192.168.17.24 with Pulse-Secure/9.0.4.1731 (Macintosh 10_14) Pulse/9.0.4.1731.
```

Comment: What are you trying to match with the first part of your regex `^(?:[^\.\n]*\.){6}`?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern didn't work because there were two different patterns but you used same pattern (\w+\s+\d+) to capture the following part:

- (Windows 10)
- (Macintosh 10_14)

I have updated the regex please check [here](https://regex101.com/r/8Ax0KC/1)